# Log Out Button on the top of Each Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

this may be a simple question but i need to create a "Log Out" button for my Web Application.  I know the code that needs to be implemented, I just don't know how I can have this button be displayed on the top of each of the web pages without continuously re-writing the code.  Is there any way to do this? Maybe have like a menu visible that is just on the top of the webpage and if there is a way to just have it on some of the webpages.  My goal is to have a "Log out" button on the top of 6 different webpages, my project has about 17 or 18 in total.

Comment: Master page?.....

Comment: hmm possibly..I can only use that for whatever specific webpages I need right?

Comment: Yes. You specify on each page what Master Page to use.

Comment: Can I have mulitple master pages in one application?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple master pages and even nested master pages in one application.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can use one master page and make use of contentplaceholder to show hide controls on individual page.